# how to "petition" show using do_shortcode in template file in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show petition in page but using template file. Is it possible?

I have used below shortcode in template file but it not worked.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[civicrm component="petition" id="1" hijack="0"]');?>
```

Also I want to show another petition in popup but also there shortcode not working

See I want to default petition show in sidebar so i get default petition Id using custom query but i can't get petition with profile form using shortcode. Any other method to get petition using id. See below query for get default petition id.

```
$petition = civicrm_api3( 'Survey', 'getsingle', array(
            'sequential' => 1,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'is_public' => 1,
            'is_template' => 0,
            'options' => array(
                'limit' => 1,
                'sort' => 'id ASC',
                'offset' => CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'offset', $instance, 0 ),
            ),
            'is_default' => array( '1'),
        ) );

$petition_id= $petition['id']
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in chat.civicrm.org the do_shortcode does work in a single template (single.php for example) but not in a sidebar.

Two examples to get this going are https://github.com/aghstrategies/civicontribute-widget and https://github.com/agh1/civievent-widget

Comment: I have checked this https://github.com/aghstrategies/civicontribute-widget 

this but i can't figure out how can i get petition?

Comment: shortcode is not working in category page and tag page. It's only work in pages and posts. It's means without post id  Shortcode not work.